# Unity: Destroy VFX Object after it finishes rendering

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm following this Unity (with C#) tutorial: [Space Shooter](https://unity3d.com/es/learn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter-tutorial/explosions?playlist=17147) where we have a space ship that gets destroyed when an asteroid hits it. The asteroid gets destroyed and the Explosion VFX renders successfully. However, the explosion objects, which are invisible at this point, are being kept in the scene forever. I want to clear them. I know this would work:

```
void DestroyObjectDelayed()
{
    // Kills the game object in 5 seconds after loading the object
    Destroy(this.gameObject, 5);
}
```

But i want to know if there is a way to make the object destroy itself when it finishes the explosion effect rendering instead of me setting some seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use the duration of the particle system. Put this on any particle system you want to destroy when it's done playing.

```
 public class DestroyParticles : MonoBehaviour
 {
     void Start()
     {
         Destroy(this.gameObject, GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().main.duration); 
     }
 }
```

Comment: [ParticleSystem](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.html) has no property called `duration` .. I'm sure you mean `GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().main.duration` see [ParticleSystem.main](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem-main.html) -> [MainModule](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.MainModule.html)

Comment: It works. Thanks! Edited the answer to add what @derHugo said

Comment: Thank y'all. This must have been for the legacy system.